# useParams in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I'm currently trying to get the id params for a route, but it keeps turning up as 'undefined' when I console log it.

Here's where the route is defined. For some reason when I console.log(id), it keeps giving 'undefined'. Even when I put it in the body, it doesn't show up.

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Header />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/monster/:id" element={<Monster />} />
        <Route path="/monsterCard" element={<MonsterCard />} />
        <Route path="/index" element={<Homepage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

And here's the component where I want to get the Id parameter

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { withRouter, useParams } from "react-router";
import "./Monster.css";

export default function Monster() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log(id);

  return <div className="monster-image-frame"></div>;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the shared code. Are there any errors? Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Where and how are the links defined that point to the monster route ? Because it seems to work fine at [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-monad-44bgjo?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import useParams from react-router but instead of it just try to import it from "react-router-dom".

```js
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: `useParams` is [exported](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.ts#L109) from `react-router`. Also, issue isn't with `useParams` hook, it's with the `id` param being undefined (*somehow*). There's also a deleted answer you probably can't see that also said to change the import that didn't help the OP resolve the issue.